# How do you perform a cross-partition query in Cosmos DB using the Python API?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb, database-partitioning

I have a collection that is partitioned by an integer with a dozen or so unique values that are more-or-less evenly distributed.

I recently migrated a Cosmos DB collection from non-partitioned to partitioned due to the size constraint.

Since then, I have been having issues with querying the database. For starters, the queries in the Document Explorer in Azure are very inefficient unless I specify the specific partition key as part of the query.

For the Python API, I must specify the specific key. If I do not, I get an error unless I specify these headers in the `options` field:

```
{'enableCrossPartitionQuery':True, 'partitionKey':'[variable name]'}
```

These have been passed to the `QueryDocuments()` function, as well as the `_fetch_function()` function (for continuation token support).

I have also replaced `True` with `'True'`, `'t'`, `'true'`, and arbitrary values. None of these actually changed the performance or behavior of their respective calls.

No data is returned at all when specifying these specific headers in the Python API.

Comment: `enableCrossPartitionQuery` true/false does not optimize your perfomance. It is just a flag you have to set so that CosmosDB allows you to do queries across multiple partitions. You usually have to provide only either `enableCrossPartitionQuery` or the `partitionKey` that covers all your expected data. Not both. It seems you should look into finding a different partition key. A dozen values is very little. `It's a best practice to have a partition key with many distinct values (hundreds to thousands at a minimum).` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data

Comment: I have read that, although I don't quite understand why that is the case if I know that all my documents will fit relatively comfortably into their respective partitions. 

Regardless, I am not getting any results, which is a query failure, rather than a performance failure (which is another issue). The data I am using has many fields that only exist on a subset of the documents, and a large number of fields of the data is nested deeply and have many missing/blank values.

Comment: In the future I will be hashing all of the data and using the first few characters of the hash as a new field to partition by, but this is not an option for me at the moment.

Comment: If your problem is that no data is returned, but executes without an exception, you will need to provide more information. Try your query in the azure portal and simplify it to get closer to the cause.

Comment: The query works in the Azure portal, but only after taking several minutes to execute. No event ID is returned, but the simple ID lookup uses tens of thousands of RUs.